# Aerospike Error Code 21

Tags: spring, aerospike

Can I maximize bin name length greater then 14?

Error while saving data in Aerospike :

**org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: Aerospike Error: Error Code 21: Bin name length greater than 14 characters or maximum bins exceeded; nested exception is com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error Code 21: Bin name length greater than 14 characters or maximum bins exceeded**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.** It is a hardcoded fixed size allocation (15 bytes - 14 max plus null). Bin name is stored with every record on SSDs. Using bin names smaller than 14 characters will not save storage space either.

Comment: New versions, starting with 4.2+, has made bin storage variable, and given you one more character,  now 15 characters max. So smaller bin names will save you on storage.  Check client version compatibility - before using 15 characters - some clients were still at 14 characters max, updated later;  i.e., clients of a later version actually implemented this feature fully, came on the server first.